# What is the most pythonic way to split a string into contiguous, overlapping list of words

Tags: python, string, list

Say I had a sentence `"The cat ate the mouse."` I want to split the sentence with `size = 2`.

So the result array becomes:

```
 ["the cat", "cat ate", "ate the", "the mouse"]
```

If my size was 3, it should become:

```
["the cat ate", "cat ate the", "ate the mouse"]
```

My method I have right now uses tons of for loops and I'm not sure if there is a best way.

Comment: Look up "ngrams python"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using list slice, you can get sub-list.

```
>>> words = "The cat ate the mouse.".rstrip('.').split()
>>> words[0:3]
['The', 'cat', 'ate']
```

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to convert the list to a string joined by delimiter:

```
>>> ' '.join(words[0:3])
'The cat ate'
```

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) provides a conside way to create words list:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> [' '.join(words[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(words) - n + 1)]
['The cat', 'cat ate', 'ate the', 'the mouse']

>>> n = 3
>>> [' '.join(words[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(words) - n + 1)]
['The cat ate', 'cat ate the', 'ate the mouse']
# [' '.join(words[0:3]), ' '.join(words[1:4]),...]
```

---

Answer (score 2):

you can use nltk library to do all the job

```
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams

text = "The cat ate the mouse."
tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
bigrams = ngrams(tokenize,3)

for gram in bigrams:
    print gram
```

what gives us:
('The', 'cat', 'ate')
('cat', 'ate', 'the')
('ate', 'the', 'mouse')
('the', 'mouse', '.')